# OpenERP 7: Adding a button on a product view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am currently playing with openERP 7. I am doing some testing and I am building my first add-on.
I want to add on every product view a "synchronize" button on a tab named "special" that has been created by another add-on (which works perfectly fine). My button displays successfully but when I click on it I obtain the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'custom_export'
```

If someone can explain me why do I have that error and how to fix it.

My add-on folder name is: custom_synchronizer, I have 4 files inside.

__init__.py

```
import product
```

__openerp.py__

```
{
    "name" : "Custom synchronizer",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "author" : "Ajite",
    "category" : "Product",
    "depends" : ["product"],
    "init_xml" : [],
    "demo_xml" : [],
    "update_xml" : ["product_view.xml"],
    "installable": True,
    "active": True
}
```

product.py

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields

class product_product(osv.osv):
        _name = 'product.product'
        _columns = {}

        def custom_export(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            f = open('/home/ajite/faytung.txt','w')
            f.write('Hi there !')
            f.close()
            return True
product_product()
```

product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_normal_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.product.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.product</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="special.product_normal_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <page name="special" position="inside">
                    <button name="custom_export" string="Export" icon="gtk-execute" type="object"/>
                </page>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gurney Alex suggestion i was able to fix that problem.

I needed to have both _name and _inherit attributes in my class.

product.py

```
from osv import fields, osv

class product_product(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.product'
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def custom_export(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

        return True 

product_product()
```

Answer (score 2):

change _name to _inherit in your product_product class definition.

Comment: Hi, thank you but it is not working. I have replaced the _name attribute by _inherit but I still have the same error.